# How to create a transaction and pass to multiple classes and methods

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a wcf web service which is instantiated on each call from clients.

The webservice creates a transaction for each client like this:

```
coreDb = new CoreDb(PROJECT.CreateTransaction(), new FactorySqlCommand());
```

Create transaction function looks like this:

```
public static SqlTransaction CreateTransaction(this ICoreProject coreProj)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(coreProj.dbStr);
            conn.Open();
            return conn.BeginTransaction();
        }
```

The SQL command factory implementation looks like this

```
public SqlCommand SqlCommand(string query,
        SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand(query, transaction.Connection, transaction);
        sql_command.Transaction = transaction;
        sql_command.Connection = transaction.Connection;
        return sql_command;
    }
```

When i try and use the following objects in a database function like this:

```
using (SqlCommand sql_command = factorySqlCommand.SqlCommand(query, transaction))
            {
                sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", user_id);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query) && sql_command != null && transaction.Connection != null)
                {
                    sql_command.Connection.Open();
                    if (sql_command.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader myReader = sql_command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (myReader.Read())
                            {
```

I get a strange error

> The connection is broken and recovery is not possible.  The connection
>   is marked by the server as unrecoverable.  No attempt was made to
>   restore the connection.

**My question is what is the correct way to instantiate a transaction for read & writes in one class to be passed to many different classes?**

Please bear in mind each function call will append SqlCommand objects so that all of the SqlCommands can be called before returning data to the requesting client.

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: error is on line:
using (SqlDataReader myReader = sql_command.ExecuteReader())

I wondered if it is related to scope of the transaction?

Comment: To me it seems like the connection is closed before you execute your query and then it says it canot restore the connection.

Comment: its strange as when i step in debugger i can see sql_command connection state is open and it passes the check before executing the read